# Manga about a teacher teaching girls with powers

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga is about a teacher he is lazy and looks unmotivated he has to teach this girl who can't and he ended making her cry and she slapped him because he was saying some mean things to her don't remember what it was also her powers which is fire everytime she gets flustered she causes an explosion that's why everyone stays away from her because they think she's dangerous

Comment: Was the teacher reincarnated into this life?

Comment: No it's modern Japan but a few people have powers

Comment: Can you remember any other details about the style of the manga or otherwise? e.g. was it comedic, serious, set in the real world or a fantasy world, was the art childish/chibi or mature, did you read it recently or years ago?

Comment: Do you remember if this took place at an all-girls school? Was the fire girl the only one he had to help, or was he in charge of a class of misfits, and later chapters would focus on other girls?

Answer (score 1):

Might this be *[Hell Teacher Nube](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Manga/HellTeacherNube)*?

[image: Front cover of Hell Teacher Nube]

> Meisuke Nueno (known as "Nube" by everyone who knows him) has been able to see spirits ever since childhood thanks to his Psychic Powers. Cool as this may sound, it has made him a constant target for all kinds of nasty creatures. Not to mention, his mentor and mother figure Minako-sensei perished because of this...
>
> Fortunately, "Hell Teacher" Nube is able to deal with these spirits by way of his magical left hand; unfortunately, this results in him attracting even more supernatural events to center on him... and to his workplace, which happens to be an elementary school. Luckily for him, his students are often more than happy to give him a hand when resolving his cases.

Izuna has pyrokinesis powers, the result of puberty and an unrequited love hitting at the same time, with the recurring gag in the episode being that when she gets emotional, the flame erupts out and burns everything around her, including her clothing, leading to healthy amounts of Scenery Censor.

Comment: No it's not this but thanks