# Manga about a teacher getting slapped by a student

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga is about a teacher who is lazy and unmotivated. He has to teach a girl with purple hair (and I think cat ears or some sort of ears) and with white gloves. Her powers are something to do with fire but she can't use them at her own will. This teacher ended up making her cry and she slaps him because he said something mean to her. Also, the only time she is able to use her powers is when she is flustered.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Manga about a teacher teaching girls with powers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/268079/manga-about-a-teacher-teaching-girls-with-powers) - https://hell-teacher-nube.fandom.com/wiki/Izuna_Hazuki

Comment: I swear I've read this before but I still can't find it. Reposting my comment from the other question. Do you remember if this took place at an all-girls school? Was the fire girl the only one he had to help, or was he in charge of a class of misfits, and later chapters would focus on other girls?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this "[Akashic Records of a Bastard Magic Instructor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akashic_Records_of_Bastard_Magic_Instructor)"?

The teacher, Glenn Radars is lazy and unmotivated. He also gets slapped by a student of his after making her cry. He also wears white gloves.